# JSON_CONTAINS in large query

Tags: mysql

Apologies in advance, I'm still quite new to JSON functions within MySQL.

I have a query that is creating a json object in the results:

```
SELECT e.id as experiment,
     JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(
                           'id', c.id,
                           'type', c.type,
                           'value', c.value,
                           'taggable', 'experiments'
                            )
                          ) as tagList
FROM Experiments e
LEFT JOIN Taggings d ON e.id = d.taggableId AND d.taggable = 'experiments' AND d.deletedAt IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Tags c ON d.tagId = c.id
GROUP BY e.id;
```

which returns the following:

| experiment | tagList |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"id": 56680, "type": "disciplines", "value": "Agronomy", "taggable": "experiments"}, {"id": 56670, "type": "disciplines", "value": "Plant Fertilization, Animal and Human Nutrition", "taggable": "experiments"}] |
| 2 | [{"id": 56693, "type": "disciplines", "value": "Animal Communications", "taggable": "experiments"}] |
| 3 | [{"id": 5624, "type": "disciplines", "value": "RNA", "taggable": "experiments"}] |

[use this link if the table isn't rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xvui.png)

I'm trying to use `JSON_CONTAINS` to filter by tag values, ie: adding `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tagList, '"Agronomy"', '$.value')` so that I only get experiment 1 returned (b/c it's the only experiment w/ a tagList that contains an object w/ value = "Agronomy".

However, when I add the WHEN statement to the end of the query, like this:

```
SELECT e.id as experiment,
     JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(
                           'id', c.id,
                           'type', c.type,
                           'value', c.value,
                           'taggable', 'experiments'
                            )
                          ) as tagList
FROM Experiments e
LEFT JOIN Taggings d ON e.id = d.taggableId AND d.taggable = 'experiments' AND d.deletedAt IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Tags c ON d.tagId = c.id
GROUP BY e.id
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tagList, '"Agronomy"', '$.value');
```

I get error  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tagList, '"Agronomy"', '$.value')' at line 14`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I think maybe running the JSON AGGs in the same query as JSON_CONTAINS is creating issues? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `GROUP BY` should follow `WHERE`

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular this returns ```Query 1 ERROR: Unknown column 'tagList' in 'where clause'```

Comment: Output column cannot be used in WHERE, it can be tested in HAVING only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test source data, not final result.

```sql
SELECT e.id as experiment,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT( 'id', c.id,
                                   'type', c.type,
                                   'value', c.value,
                                   'taggable', 'experiments' )) as tagList
FROM Experiments e
LEFT JOIN Taggings d ON e.id = d.taggableId AND d.taggable = 'experiments' AND d.deletedAt IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Tags c ON d.tagId = c.id
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING SUM(c.value = 'Agronomy')
```